# Can Expectation-Maximization algorithm with batch update diverge?

Tags: algorithms

I am using EM to uncover a continuous hidden variable $z$ (E-step), then maximizing the model prediction (M-step) with parameters $\theta$. The complete data are $[x,z]$.

I can formulate the *E-step* as follows

$$p(t|x,\theta^{old}) = \mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_z \sum log(p(t|x,z,\theta^{old}))$$

since I am looking for the most probable value of $z$ according to my current model parameters $\theta$.

Then I am looking for matching $\theta$ to the newly obtained $z$ by *M-step*

$$\theta^{new} = \mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_{\theta} \sum log(p(t|x,z,\theta))$$

**batch update**

Now about the $x$. I have 3 batches of the $x=\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\}$, such that *E-step* produces 3 batches of complete data $[x,z]=\{[x_{1}, z_{1}],[x_{2},z_{2}],[x_{3},z_{3}]\}$.

The *E-step* receives 3 different batches in 3 consecutive iterations. The M-step updates on every $[x,z]$. In other words, the M-step is the same, while the E-step iterates over 3 different data, with the model parameters $\theta$ being constantly updated.

---

Problem

The algorithm converges to the optimum (or quite close), and then diverges. *The log-likelihood of the data being generated by the model is increasing (until the optimum) and then **decreases**.*

---

Question

Can batch update cause a stable algorithm to diverge ?

In other words, can the batch update cause the E-M algorithm to diverge (literary decreasing the log-likelihood) ?

If so, please update me with some literature.